# Table Valued Function Performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server Table Valued function like below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDeptName ( @DId INT )
RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN
        ( SELECT    DeptID ,
                    DeptName ,
                    Location
          FROM      dbo.department
          WHERE     Deptno = @DId
        );
```

Now I want to get data from `Employee` table using this Table Valued Function. Which one is gives better performance for 50k records from the below 3 scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.employee
WHERE   deptname IN ( SELECT    deptname
                      FROM      dbo.GetDeptName(50) );
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.employee e
        JOIN dbo.GetDeptName (50) fn ON e.deptname = fn.deptname;
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.employee e
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   dbo.GetDeptName (50) fn
                 WHERE  e.deptname = fn.deptname );
```

Comment: Just run it and see for yourself. And your function has no where clause

Comment: does your queries work

Comment: yes these are working...

Comment: Do you realize that you are not using the parameter @DId anywhere ?.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: sorry I modified...

Comment: The scenario 2 query is not semantically the same so it makes no sense to compare performance of that to the others.

Answer (score 1):

All the three queries are not optimized:

Its not a good practice use function in query because the SQL Engine executes the function for all the records of the employee table in this case.

Anyway, to know what is the best of three you can run this command:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

select * from dbo.employee where deptname in(select deptname from dbo.GetDeptName(50))

select * from dbo.employee e join dbo.GetDeptName(50) fn on e.deptname =fn.deptname

select * from dbo.employee e where exists(select 1 from dbo.GetDeptName(50) fn where e.deptname =fn.deptname)
```

Then check in message panel ( at the right of results ) the output.

You will receive 3 message like this:

> Table 'employee'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

The query that has less value number in Scan, Logical Reads and physical reads is the query that performs better.

Ciao

Answer (score -1):

Try this.it could be the best way to join with the functions.

```
SELECT  *
FROM   dbo.employee e
cross apply ( SELECT deptname FROM dbo.GetDeptName(e.deptid))
where e.deptid=50
```